# Does okhttp can tell whether the local cache is out of date OR(AND) the server side has just updated automatically, how?

Tags: android, caching, okhttp

I know the okhttp has cached mechanism, and we can force it to use cache or just to get info from server only. But what I want to know is that:

1. Can we set a period of validity to the cache, so if the cache is out of date, the okhttp will get the info we need from the internet instead of our obsolute local cached info?
2. Can okhttp tell if the server side has updated info, so even if the local cached date is not out of date, it can still get the latest info from the internet instead of the local cache automatically?

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. OkHttp’s response cache follows [RFC 7234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7234#section-5.2) which has rich options for configuring the lifetime of a response. Client or server may specify the maximum age of a response.
2. Yes. Use the [CacheControl.FORCE_NETWORK](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/CacheControl.html) header to workaround a potentially stale cached response.